# Graphql object with random key names

Tags: graphql

Output from a db-query:

```
    "_id": "5cd532a8452d22435be6a9ac", 
    "properties": {
        "somerandomname": "asd,
        "someotherrandomname": "adsad"
    }
```

How do I build a graphql type of this?

Something like:

```
export const aaa = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'aaa',
  fields: () => ({
    _id: {
      type: GraphQLString
    },
    properties: {
      type: GraphQLObjectType 
    },
  })
});
```

But GraphQLObjectType requires a config.

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GraphQL Blackbox / "Any" type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45598812/graphql-blackbox-any-type)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to achieve that you would have to define a custom `GraphQLScalarType` that returns `json`. You can read more about it in [custom-scalars](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/graphql-tools/scalars#custom-scalars).

Or you could just use the package [graphql-type-json](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/graphql-tools/scalars#using-a-package) that basically is an implementation of a `GraphQLScalarType` that returns json, something like:

```
const {GraphQLJSON} = require('graphql-type-json');

const aaa = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'aaa',
    fields: () => ({
        _id: {
            type: GraphQLString
        },
        properties: {
            type: GraphQLJSON
        },
    })
});

const RootQuery = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'RootQueryType',
    fields: {
        myField: {
            type: aaa,
            resolve(parent, args) {
                // Here: return your object as it is
                // for example:
                return {
                    _id: "this",
                    properties: {
                        somerandomname: "asd",
                        someotherrandomname: "asdad",
                        "what?!": "it also has strings",
                        noway: [
                            "what about them arrays"
                        ]
                    }
                };
            }
        },
    }
})
```

Then if you query:

```
{
  myField {
    _id
    properties
  }
}
```

You will get the output:

```
{
  "data": {
    "myField": {
      "_id": "this",
      "properties": {
        "somerandomname": "asd",
        "someotherrandomname": "asdad",
        "what?!": "it also has strings",
        "noway": [
          "what about them arrays"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't get it. Can you provide example?

Comment: @Joe, I updated with an example of using the package `graphql-type-json`

Comment: Thanks. But I dont know the property names beforehand? And its always strings. properties: { "somestring": "anotherstring"}

Comment: You don't have to, you just have to return whatever you get from the db on the resolver.