# Apollo Server Slow Performance when resolving large data

Tags: graphql, apollo-server

When resolving large data I notice a very slow performance, from the moment of returning the result from my resolver to the client.

I assume `apollo-server` iterates over my result and checks the types... either way, the operation takes too long.

In my product I have to return large amount of data all at once, since its being used, all at once, to draw a chart in the UI. There is no pagination option for me where I can slice the data.

I suspect the slowness coming from `apollo-server` and not my resolver object creation.

Note, that I log the time the resolver takes to create the object, its fast, and not the bottle neck.

Later operations performed by `apollo-server`, which I dont know how to measure, takes a-lot of time.

Now, I have a version, where I return a custom scalar type JSON, the response, is much much faster. But I really prefer to return my `Series` type.

I measure the difference between the two types (`Series` and `JSON`) by looking at the network panel.

when AMOUNT is set to 500, and the type is `Series`, it takes ~1.5s (that is seconds)

when AMOUNT is set to 500, and the type is `JSON`, it takes ~150ms (fast!)

when AMOUNT is set to 1000, and the type is `Series`, its very slow...

when AMOUNT is set to 10000, and the type is `Series`, I'm getting JavaScript heap out of memory (which is unfortunately what we experience in our product)

---

I've also compared `apollo-server` performance to `express-graphql`, the later works faster, yet still not as fast as returning a custom scalar JSON.

when AMOUNT is set to 500, `apollo-server`, network takes 1.5s

when AMOUNT is set to 500, `express-graphql`, network takes 800ms

when AMOUNT is set to 1000, `apollo-server`, network takes 5.4s

when AMOUNT is set to 1000, `express-graphql`, network takes 3.4s

---

The Stack:

```
"dependencies": {
  "apollo-server": "^2.6.1",
  "graphql": "^14.3.1",
  "graphql-type-json": "^0.3.0",
  "lodash": "^4.17.11"
}
```

---

The Code:

```
const _ = require("lodash");
const { performance } = require("perf_hooks");
const { ApolloServer, gql } = require("apollo-server");
const GraphQLJSON = require('graphql-type-json');

// The GraphQL schema
const typeDefs = gql`
  scalar JSON

  type Unit {
    name: String!
    value: String!
  }

  type Group {
    name: String!
    values: [Unit!]!
  }

  type Series {
    data: [Group!]!
    keys: [Unit!]!
    hack: String
  }

  type Query {
    complex: Series
  }
`;

const AMOUNT = 500;

// A map of functions which return data for the schema.
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    complex: () => {
      let before = performance.now();

      const result = {
        data: _.times(AMOUNT, () => ({
          name: "a",
          values: _.times(AMOUNT, () => (
            {
              name: "a",
              value: "a"
            }
          )),
        })),
        keys: _.times(AMOUNT, () => ({
          name: "a",
          value: "a"
        }))
      };

      let after = performance.now() - before;

      console.log("resolver took: ", after);

      return result
    }
  }
};

const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers: _.assign({ JSON: GraphQLJSON }, resolvers),
});

server.listen().then(({ url }) => {
  console.log(` Server ready at ${url}`);
});
```

---

The gql Query for the Playground (for type Series):

```
query {
  complex {
    data {
      name
      values {
        name
        value
      }
    }
    keys {
      name
      value
    }
  }
}
```

---

The gql Query for the Playground (for custom scalar type JSON):

```
query {
  complex
}
```

Here is a working example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/apollo-server-performance-issue-i7fk7

Any leads/ideas would be highly appreciated!

Comment: not graphql related - you're testing only node js performance (object creation) - this way you can even dig cryptocurrency in resolver and blame graphql

Comment: @xadm I dont think it is graphql related either, I did not say that. I think it is related to the following operation of `apollo-server` (regardless of it being a gql lib, if that helps) after I create the object in my resolver. My object creation is fast, what happens next is slow, up to out of memory heap... I think my stringify example proves it. My question is how to overcome this limit?

Comment: you didn't provide overal process results vs logged object creation time ... question is: do you really need all this nested data **at once** ... client cache will normalize it taking a lot of time, too

Comment: @xadm I dont know how to measure the overall process result, since it happens inside apollo-server internal code, I believe. I did measure my resolver object creation time which I am logging, as I wrote, you can see it in the example. The other thing I was able to measure is the network time, and the different results when I stringify the object and not. Regarding if I need it all at once, well right now yes, it is part of UI graph I draw on the client, or a table with many columns. There is no pagination option that may allow me to fetch parts unfortunately.

Comment: probably you don't need small granular data - you can use [custom scalar types](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/graphql-tools/scalars/) to return entire series as one object - if really need detailed granulation you can do it later, client side only

Comment: I would be interested in streaming or deferring, eventually, but those are not yet supported.

Comment: you can use subscriptions, polling

Comment: @xadm custom scalar JSON is a better solution then my stringify hack, also as fast. Still does not feel right, as I loose much of the gql concept along the way.

Comment: @sergelerner I have no answer but we are running into similar issues. Would like to ask, what do you consider "large data"? How many documents are you querying? I mean not returning but what is the db size... Approximately... Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There's a related open issue [here](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/issues/723). Lee Byron summed it up pretty well:

> I think the TL;DR of this issue is that GraphQL has some overhead and that reducing that overhead is non-trivial and removing it completely may not be an option. Ultimately GraphQL.js is still responsible for making API boundary guarantees about the shape and type of the returned data and by design does not trust the underlying systems. In other words GraphQL.js does runtime type checking and sub-selection and this has some cost.

The benefits that GraphQL offers (validation, sub-selection, etc.) inevitably incur some overhead as they require additional processing of the data you're returning. And unfortunately, this overhead scales with the size of the data. I imagine if you were to implement a REST endpoint that supported partial responses and did response validation using something like Swagger or Joi, you'd encounter a similar issue.

The "heap out of memory" error means exactly what it says -- you're running out of memory on the heap. You can try to alleviate this by [manually increasing the limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38558989/node-js-heap-out-of-memory).

Typically, large datasets like this should be broken up by implementing pagination. If that's not an option, utilizing a [custom scalar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56196984/6024220) will be the next best approach. The biggest downside to this approach is that clients consuming your API will not be able to request specific fields inside the JSON object you return. Outside of [patching GraphQL.js](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/issues/723#issuecomment-357474466), there's really no other alternative to speed up the responses and reduce your memory usage.

Answer (score 2):

**Comment summary**

This data structure/types:

- are not individual entities;
- just a series of [groupped] data;
- don't need normalization;
- won't be normalized properly in apollo cache (no `id` fields);

This way **this dataset is not the graphQL was designed for.** Of course graphQL still can be used for fetching this data but type parsing/matching should be disabled.

Using [custom scalar types](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/graphql-tools/scalars/) (`graphql-type-json`) can be a solution. If you need some hybrid solution - you can type `Group.values` as json (instead entire `Series`). Groups still should have an `id` field if you want to use normalized cache [access].

### Alternative

You can use [`apollo-link-rest`](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/link/links/rest/) for fetching 'pure' json data (file) leaving type parsing/matching to be client side only.

### More advanced alternative

If you want to use one graphql endpoint ...
write own link - use directives - 'ask for json, get typed' - mix of two above. Sth like in rest link with de-/serializers.

---

In both alternatives - **why do you really need it?** Just for drawing? Not worth the effort. No pagination but hopefully streaming (live updates?) ... no cursors ... load more (subscriptions/polling) by ... last time update? Doable but 'not feel right'.

Comment: what do you mean by "this dataset is not the graphQL was designed for"? would be happy to understand more. thanks!