# Can I define a GraphQL field to be any valid json?

Tags: json, typescript, graphql

I know it's possible to define a field with some type. But What if I want the field to contain any kind of json data? how can that be defined?

Comment: How about a generic scalar

Comment: Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56196984/6024220) for a detailed explanation.